# Java Double convert to Int round

Tags: java, int, double

I want to convert a double value to int when and only when 2 numbers after the dot are 0.

**Example**

`double x = 25.001`

Comment: OK, what is stopping you from doing so? Is there any *specific* problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
double x = 25.001;
int i = (int) x;
System.out.println(x);//Input
if (x - i <= 0.01) {
    x = (int) x;
}
System.out.println(x);//Output
```

**RESULT**

```
Input                Output
25.001               25.0
25.011               25.011
```

---

If you want to use a second variable you can use :

```
int y = 0;
if (x - i <= 0.01) {    
    y = (int) x;
}
```

**Note**

But note, in case your input is not correct, you will always get 0, i like the first solution it is good then the second.

Answer (score 0):

if(x-Integer.parseInt(x)>=0.001)
 //Convert here

Answer (score 0):

That rounded number you then cannot store in a `double`, as a `double` is *always* an approximation of a real value - of a series of a (negative) power of 2.

So you should go for `BigDecimal` as many do that want to do financial software.

If you did something like:

```
double adjustWhenCloseToInt(double x) {
    long n = Math.round(x); // Could overflow for large doubles
    if (Math.abs(x - n) < 0.01) {
        x = n;
    }
    return x;
}
```

A simple

```
x = adjustWhenCloseToInt(x);
System.out.print(x);
```

Could still print 0.00000001 or such.

The solution there is

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", x);
```

Or better use a localized **MessageFormat** (thousand separators and such).

As floating point always bears rounding errors, I would in general go for BigDecimal, though it is a circumstantial class to use. Take care to use String constructors:

```
new BigDecimal("3.99");
```

As they then can maintain a precision of 2.